# How to get live locators during run time in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am automating a web-page which contains some actions, but those action elements are getting changed frequently which causes the exception. Is there any way to get live elements during run time or any other solution in selenium webdriver?

Environment: `Eclipse phone m4`, `Java 8`, `Selenium Webdriver 3.8.1`, `Chrome 64`, `Windows 8`.

Code snippet:

```
driver.get("https://www.qcommission.com");
driver.switchTo().frame("60343815682962");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header_42']"), "Demo Inquiry"));
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.id("input_24")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("input_24")).sendKeys(name);
driver.findElement(By.id("input_16")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("input_16")).sendKeys(emailjoin);
driver.findElement(By.id("input_50")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("input_50")).sendKeys(count_of_payee);
driver.findElement(By.id("input_51_full")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("input_51_full")).sendKeys(phone_number);
driver.findElement(By.id("input_48")).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
//driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Thread.sleep(50000);

if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Thank you for your inquiry!"))
{
    System.out.println("PASS - Demo Inquiry");
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
else
{
    System.out.println("FAIL - Demo Inquiry");

    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: will you please share code snippet..

Comment: You can get element by using its text.

Comment: Share you HTML atleast, So we can understand which element u want to get.

Comment: Hi Vikas and Sagar, please find below the code snippet.Eg.  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ctl00_ltaccordian']/a")).click(); Here we hard coded the xpath element which we get it from browser by inspecting it. but its possible this element get changed in future..so we will get an exception

Comment: Hi Mahesh, for input fields we dont have text right..

Comment: @Jaya can you share code snippet and website (if possible) in question itself?

Comment: @MaheshKaria , updated code snippet with website. please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of id you can use XPath as follows:

**for text field below Name:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Name')]/../*/input")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Name')]/../*/input")).sendKeys(name);
```

**for text field below E-mail:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'E-mail')]/../*/input")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'E-mail')]/../*/input")).sendKeys(name);
```

**for text field below Count of payees:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Count of Payees')]/../*/input")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Count of Payees')]/../*/input")).sendKeys(name);
```

**for text field below Phone number:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Phone Number')]/../div/span/input")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Phone Number')]/../div/span/input")).sendKeys(name);
```

Check if it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. It works for me.But I don't  how you formed this locator? Please help me.

Comment: @Jaya If it has worked for you then please accept and support answer by upvoting it.

To find elements/locators Refer: https://www.webperformance.com/load-testing-tools/blog/real-browser-manual/building-a-testcase/how-locate-element-the-page/ 

Its good blog for starters also you can drop chat request or webex or skype to me if you are keen to learn more about it.

Comment: Sure, Thanks Mahesh.